# How do I get debugging symbols using GDB attach to stripped application if i have not stripped application version?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, arm

For stripped application has not been made objcopy --only-keep-debug

Answer (score 1):

You can simply start debugger with gdb  and do attach to you running stripped executable.

You could also use symbol-file  in gdb to point it to symbols.

Comment: I try 
1) gdb -p 4072 
2)symbol-file /tmp/telemetry 
3) bt #0  0x40439276 in ?? () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x404a8488 in poll () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000f980 in ?? ()
#3  0x0000f980 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1be5c: main. (2 locations)

Comment: Does gdb say it found symbols in /tmp/telemetry? Do you use some other library that calls poll or do you do this in your code?

Comment: Gdb say that found debug symbols.
(gdb) symbol-file /tmp/telemetry_debug_only 
Reading symbols from /tmp/telemetry_debug_only...done.
warning: File "/lib/libthread_db.so.1" auto-loading has been declined by your `auto-load safe-path' set to "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load".
warning: Unable to find libthread_db matching inferior's thread library, thread debugging will not be available.

I use other library that calls poll.